# How to install java 3d in ubuntu

Tags: 3d, java

I'd recently asked a question for getting started in game development from where I was suggested for the book "Killer Game Programming-Java".

On the [page](http://fivedots.coe.psu.ac.th/~ad/jg/code/index.html) there is a java 3d program which needs to be installed. I'd downloaded and installed `java3d` file from [here](https://java3d.dev.java.net/binary-builds.html) and also from the sun/oracle's site. But the program given [there](http://fivedots.coe.psu.ac.th/~ad/jg/code/HelloUniverse.zip) is not working.

I would like to know how to install that java3d package in Ubuntu 10.10, and also is there any need to set environmental variable `$PATH` or `classpath` for java, and if so, how to do that?

The downloaded version of java3d is 1.5 and it is a .bin file.

Comment: Is this the right place to ask? Well, I'm sure someone will know. I remember I had some problems installing Java on my Ubuntu machine as well. But then I realized I don't need it.

Comment: @Bane: As the problem arrived from here that's why asked this question here. Might somebody had found this problem also, so he can provide the solution. Well there is another [site](http://askubuntu.com) where all ubunut related questions are asked.

Comment: OK then, good luck! :)

Answer (score 2):

How did you install the file? You say it's a .bin file, so you should run "sh j3d-1_5_2-linux-i586.bin" from a shell to install/extract it. That's how I unpacked the JDK from Oracle. 
In order to run the examples you have to put any necessary libraries from Java3D into the classpath of the example you want to compile or run. Doing this on the commandline is cumbersome, you might want to use an IDE like Eclipse, IntelliJ or Netbeans.

However, "Killer Game Programming" is outdated in terms of the Java version they use. You might want to read it, understand the basic principles and then code a game using a current Java version. If you want to create 3D graphics in Java, you should look into [Lightweight Java Game Library](http://lwjgl.org/)